# How to use plot_importance function with MultiOutputRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I use the code blow to get multi output.

But I got the error message when I want to plot importance.

"ValueError: tree must be Booster, XGBModel or dict instance"

How to fix this problem?
Or is there any other way to get the feature importance?

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import plot_importance

X = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7]])
y = np.array([[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]])

model_ = MultiOutputRegressor(xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:linear',n_jobs=-1))
model_.fit(X, y)
pred = model_.predict(X)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
plot_importance(model_,height=0.5,ax=ax,max_num_features=3)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(15,6))
plot_importance(model.estimators_[0],height=0.5,ax=ax[0],max_num_features=20)
plot_importance(model.estimators_[1],height=0.5,ax=ax[1],max_num_features=20)
plot_importance(model.estimators_[2],height=0.5,ax=ax[2],max_num_features=20)
plt.show()
```